# Promises function in Typescript "type void is not assignable ..."

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have just started using Typescript.  One problem I can't seem to solve without cheating the Typescript system and using `any` type is the following:

I have a function that returns a promise:

```
  saveExpirableToken(tokenField: string, tokenExpiresField: string, tokenExpiresAt: Date) {
    return new Promise<UserDocument>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.generateResetToken((err: Error, resetToken: string) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }

        this[tokenField] = resetToken
        this[tokenExpiresField] = tokenExpiresAt
        resolve(this.save())
      })
    })
  },
```

I call elsewhere the following

```
    let winningUser: UserDocument = await randomUser.saveExpirableToken(
      'wonEverythingToken',
      'wonEverythingTokenExpires',
      moment().add(1, 'year').toDate() // add one year as expiration to claiming prize
    )
```

The Typescript error I get is: `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'UserDocument'`

What am I missing with my function declaration?  And how do I handle Promises with Typescript such that I can tell Typescript that `winningUser` will in fact be of type `UserDocument`

** Edit **

```
  generateResetToken(callback: (err: Error | null, token?: string) => Promise<UserDocument>) {
    const byteSize = 16
    crypto.randomBytes(byteSize, (err, resetToken) => {
      if (err) { callback(err) }

      callback(null, resetToken.toString('hex'))
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the type definition of `this.save()` method, it seems like it does not return `UserDocument` but instead returning `void`.

I've created a playground link and it shows that your other type definitions is working just fine: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgEQPYGMCuBbCA7YKAXigG8AoKKqPAQ1wC4o5hEBLPAcwG5yBfcoIBmmPOmBtUeZrQBuEAKIAPMG0S0ARgBsIAFVQBrfAApgh-ADE2ELQBMmLdlwA0UM0bzLViCHCs37ZlYOTld3fC81XwBBYCZkWmAIAEoySmofYExEaTwIAHcoAAVEVGw2BAAeeCQ0LFwCAD5jYx84VC15Vx8AKwhxVKJGtOpRqDaO%20WNSGnoIJgAiAClUAAs8Bag%20ZPSqbf5BdCkWcdFiKFo4EDEoY0HhilGdQnyOPBCaxHPafNo2QjgckUKjUmh0%20g8xgA5PkpAp5IgQMBViEIfgoc5dmMYXCEUiUVw0Z4QW0MTQClAEkk7sleFijnh2joAHRaVCcYyvPDvLifHZ8aiCRCiO7cIA)

Comment: This seems right.  They should call `this.save()` (and wait for it if it's `async`) and then resolve with `this`.

Comment: I'm specifically using MongoDB and Mongoose.  Based on these docs `document.save()` should return a promise that resolves to the document that was saved:  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-save .

Comment: I believe my issue here is with how `generateResetToken` is working as well.  

I've tried to add typescript (see edit) to the function to say it will receive a callback that is a function that will return a promise to the user document.

Comment: Looks like the error coming from the type definition of the `generateResetToken`. The `callback` should return nothing so you may want to change the return type of `generateResetToken` to `void`. Just to make sure again, which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: What is the type of `randomUser`? Could you also provide the code of `save` method? `this.save()` means calling `save` method of your object (which I guess will eventually call `save` provided by Mongoose)

Comment: This ended up being the simplest and silly mistake on my part where though I had everything right in the above, my interface definition was never changed to `Promise<UserDocument>`